# IO Exception on some XP systems getting WMI Disk information

Tags: vb.net, ioerror

**The Problem**

Two machines display the runtime error: `IO Exception The device is not ready`. This only happens for 2 out of 8 machines I've tested it on.

These are server versions from SBS 2003 to Windows XP, Vista, 7,8,8.1, Server 2012. It's a broad range.

The two machines in question are:

- Windows Server 2003 SP2 *(.NET framework V4/V4.0 both installed)*
- Windows XP SP3 *(.NET framework V4/V4.0 both installed*)

Please note: I installed Windows XP fresh on a VM, installed .NET framework 4.0 and the program ran without error.

**My Investigation and Testing**

To start things of my application is targeted to .NET framework 4.0 and all referenced external .DLLS are included in the application start folder.

From research I determined that the error was related to drive access. In my application there is two instances where I specifically query the system drive of the device. Once to grab disk space and the other to grab the serial.

So I created two programs, one has the function I use to grab diskspace and the other has the function I use to grab the HDD Serial.

I ran both programs on the work machines and low and behold a message box was displayed with free disk space and the HDD serial *(no surprise there.)*

I tried it on the above machines that display IO errors and I receive *(for both applications)* `programname.exe is not a valid Win32 application.`

^ That's weird right?

Here are the two functions in question.

```
Public Shared Function getHardwareID() As String

    Dim drive As String = "C"
    Dim disk As ManagementObject = _
        New ManagementObject _
        ("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=""" + drive + ":""")
    disk.Get()
    Return disk("VolumeSerialNumber").ToString()

End Function


Public Shared Function getFreeDiskSpace() As String

    Dim freespacekb = My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives.Item(0).AvailableFreeSpace.ToString
    freespacekb = Format(freespacekb / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, "#0.00") _
        & " GB Free"
    Return freespacekb.ToString
End Function
```

**Yes "C" is the drive letter for both machines.**

**EDIT**:

I targeted one of the IO Tests to .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile and it ran! Although with an exception, see paste bin below.

http://pastebin.com/FRngUeBN

Comment: If you put a `Try/Catch` in each routine, and check for IO exceptions, then exit gracefully, you won't get the runtime errors.  The WMI version presumes WMI/admin rights are available, and the `My.Computer` version presumes the C: is the first item in the `.Drives` collection.   When running your code on multiple machines, you really should be doing more error checking.

Comment: Is it a 32/64 bit problem?

Comment: @JohnKoerner I ran it on a Fresh 32bit Windows XP and it worked no problem...

Comment: Are you targeting the .Net Full Profile and the target machines only have the .Net Client profile installed?

Comment: These are ancient operating systems.  .NET projects created on VS2012 and up with the default settings don't run on them anymore.  To what degree their VM emulates a real disk drive so that these WMI queries can work is unclear, don't get your hopes up.

Comment: @HansPassant What would I need to stay clear off to target these old OS's?

Comment: @JohnKoerner I switched it up to the client profile and different error this time, please take a look.

Comment: `Drives.Item(0)` huh? Hard-coded index 0... what's at that index on the problematic machines?! Bad practice.

Comment: The system drive is not always on drive C.

Comment: @usr in this case they are

Comment: @SamuelNicholson and what's on index 0? How did you make sure that Item(0) is what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since these are old machines, there are several things which may be at play.  I have an XP  machine (for Civ3) and it too failed with an IO Exception on one of the calls .  I extrapolated for the other.

For the VolumeSerial, it tries WMI first, then polls the API if that fails.  For Freespace, I got rid of all the VisualBasic calls and replaced it with NET calls to `DriveInfo` and then a call to `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` if NET cant deliver.

The Code (I suggest a class for all this):

Imports

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text
```

NativeMethods:

```
<DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function GetVolumeInformation(ByVal RootPathName As String,
        ByVal VolumeNameBuffer As System.Text.StringBuilder,
        ByVal VolumeNameSize As UInt32,
        ByRef VolumeSerialNumber As UInt32,
        ByRef MaximumComponentLength As UInt32,
        ByRef FileSystemFlags As UInt32, _
        ByVal FileSystemNameBuffer As System.Text.StringBuilder,
        ByVal FileSystemNameSize As UInt32
        ) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean

End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(lpDirectoryName As String,
                                 ByRef lpFreeBytesAvailable As ULong,
                                 ByRef lpTotalNumberOfBytes As ULong,
                                 ByRef lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes As ULong
                                 ) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

<Flags>
Private Enum FileSystemFeature As UInteger
    CaseSensitiveSearch = 1
    CasePreservedNames = 2
    UnicodeOnDisk = 4
    PersistentACLS = 8
    FileCompression = &H10
    VolumeQuotas = &H20
    SupportsSparseFiles = &H40
    SupportsReparsePoints = &H80
    VolumeIsCompressed = &H8000
    SupportsObjectIDs = &H10000
    SupportsEncryption = &H20000
    NamedStreams = &H40000
    ReadOnlyVolume = &H80000
    SequentialWriteOnce = &H100000
    SupportsTransactions = &H200000
End Enum
```

If both alternatives fail for DriveSpace, it returns -1, an obviously illegal value. I did this instead of throwing an exception.  *Formatting* the return should really be separate from *getting* the return which would make evaluating the return easier, but I left it the way you had it.

I changed the calls to require a drive letter to poll to help eliminate some errors like trying to poll a nonexistant drive.  The WMI versions could easily be modified to work on first fixed disk or even the 'Windows' drive, depending on what this is for.

```
Public Shared Function getFreeDiskSpace(drvName As String) As String

    ' since this fails on just some machines
    ' AND the machines mentioned are old, they may well have floppy drives

    ' failure signal
    Dim freespace As Double = -1

    Dim myFreeBytesAvailable As ULong
    Dim myTotalNumberOfBytes As ULong
    Dim myTotalNumberOfFreeBytes As ULong

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(drvName) Then
        Return freespace.ToString
    End If

    ' try the NET method
    Dim di As DriveInfo() = DriveInfo.GetDrives

    Try
        For Each drv In di
            ' look for desired drive in list
            If drv.Name.ToLowerInvariant.StartsWith(drvName.ToLowerInvariant(0)) Then

                ' apply your desired logic... 
                ' check only fixed drives for this use?
                ' at least check if they are ready
                'If drv.DriveType = DriveType.Fixed
                ' If drv.IsReady

                ' min test
                If drv.DriveType = drv.IsReady Then
                    freespace = drv.TotalFreeSpace
                End If

                Exit For
            End If

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    ' no answer yet, ask the API; should always work on valid drives
    If freespace = -1 Then
        ' format drv letter to name
        Dim drvpath As String = String.Format("{0}:\", drvName.ToLowerInvariant(0))
        ' call API
        If GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(drvpath, myFreeBytesAvailable, 
                    myTotalNumberOfBytes, myTotalNumberOfFreeBytes) Then
            freespace = myFreeBytesAvailable
        End If

    End If

    ' format bytes
    If freespace > -1 Then
        freespace = freespace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024
    End If

    ' ret string
    Return freespace.ToString("#00.00 Gb Free")

End Function
```

The Volume serial is broken into 2 procs.  The main public one:

```
' again, call with drive letter "C"
Public Shared Function getHardwareID(drvLtr As String) As String
    Dim volSerial As String = ""
    Dim drive As String = (drvLtr.ToLower)(0)

    Try
        Dim disk As ManagementObject = _
            New ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=""" + drive + ":""")

        disk.Get()
        volSerial = disk("VolumeSerialNumber").ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' call private API version for help
        volSerial = GetVolumeSerialFromAPI(drive)
    Finally

    End Try

    Return volSerial

End Function
```

Private helper when WMI cant do the job:

```
Private Shared Function GetVolumeSerialFromAPI(driveLetter As String) As String
    ' format drive letter
    Dim myDrvLtr As String = (driveLetter(0) & ":\").ToLower

    ' allocate space
    Dim volname As New StringBuilder(261)
    Dim fsName As New StringBuilder(261)
    Dim sernum, maxlen As UInt32

    ' out_Flags
    Dim flags As FileSystemFeature

    If GetVolumeInformation(myDrvLtr, volname, volname.Capacity,
                            sernum, maxlen, flags, 
                            fsName, fsName.Capacity) Then
        ' format to Hex like WMI
        Return sernum.ToString("X")
    Else
        Return ""
    End If

End Function
```

I *suspect* the underlying issue is old floppy drives at `Drives.Item(0)`.  The code did not check if they were FixedDrives nor if that drive was ready.  This is part of the reason this one requires a DriveLetter.  You could easily change it to get the VolumeSerial for the First Fixed disk or Windows Drive depending on what this is for.

Four procedures is a little bit overkill, the 2 API version should always work, but since we are talking about pretty old systems, a failsafe doesn't seem like a bad idea.
Plus, as I said I could only reproduce one of the errors, so a multi-pronged solution seems prudent.

Comment: Thank you for this, I haven't had a chance to test this out but I will do tomorrow. I'll come back and let you know how it goes, thanks.

Comment: Sure thing. Along with a few other changes, falling back to Win32 API if NET and/or WMI fails should work.

Comment: I have another IO error for a different part of code but for the same old machines, would you be willing to assist me with that if I ask another question?

Comment: I will if I can - my XP test machine started acting up 2 days ago, which might hinder testing.